# This line make Rust errors and I cannot understand what does it mean

Tags: rust

The following is a simplified version of my real project code. It may appear as convoluted code because I'm using a ["Clean Code Architecture"](https://threedots.tech/post/introducing-clean-architecture/) approach where I have `adapters / ports / app (aka controllers) / domain` "sections".

This approach is coming from my Golang codebase which is obviously simpler to write (no lifetimes there). The `handle` function is the code in the controller: it doesn't care about persistence (DB) or other repositories: it only executes business logic.

So I'm using this pattern because it's very easy (in Go) to pass DB transactions within `player_create` (repository) function (I borrowed this idea from here).

I can change whatever I want, even the `lambda` type (which maybe is the guilty one here).

Is there a better aproach?

After all what I'm trying to write is just a "simple" web server for elegant business CRUD-ish app.

This code works: [Rust Explorer Playground](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b/mbw20m)

```rust
let domain_player = lambda(PlayerCreateLambdaArgs {
    input,
    shirt_next_value: Box::new(|model: &str| {
        Box::pin(shirt_get_next_and_increase(&mut tx, model))
    }),
})
.await?;
```

and this not: [Rust Explorer Playground](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b/3y3hi2)

```rust
let shirt_next_value =
    Box::new(|model: &str| Box::pin(shirt_get_next_and_increase(&mut tx, model)));

let domain_player = lambda(PlayerCreateLambdaArgs {
    input,
    shirt_next_value,
})
.await?;
```

**and this is the ONLY CHANGE!**

What does this even mean?

```
expected struct `Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<i64, std::string::String>> + Send>>`
found struct `Pin<Box<impl Future<Output = Result<i64, std::string::String>>>>`
```

Comment: `impl Trait` syntax means it's a concrete but unnameable type with usual static dispatch, while `dyn Trait` means it is a dynamically dispatched trait object.

Comment: Thanks. But why the error?

Comment: Because those are different types. In the first example rust figured out that it should perform unsizing coercion automatically, in the second it kept concrete boxed type.

Comment: Ok and how can I fix this?

Comment: You'd have to add a type annotation to `let shirt_next_value`. I recommend creating a type alias like `type NextValueFn<'a> = ...` and using that in annotations.